# the set of integers A,B are defined by A={13k-5;k=1,2,...,2013} and B={17n-10;n=1,2,...,2013}. Compute the number of elements in A union B.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As, the number of elements in both sets are 2013 and |A∪B|=|A|+|B|-|A∩B| 
but I don't know how to find |A∩B|. Can anyone help me please to find its solution.

Comment: When is $13k-5=17n-10$?

Comment: this is exactly what the OP is asking

Comment: Do you know the chinese remainder theorem ?

Answer (score 1):

We have $k=-5=8\bmod 13$ and $k=-10=7\bmod 17$ iff $k=177\bmod 221$ (Note that $13\times17=221$).

So the values in $A\cap B$ are $177, 398, ... 26034=117\cdot221+177$. Hence $|A\cap B|=118$ and so $|A\cup B|=4026-118=3908$.